# Java 2d Library - Sprite Color Key Support

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, 2d, color-key

I'm building a 2d game with box2d and opengl.

Turns out, opengl does not support color keying (removing the background color of a sprite). This is obviously ridiculous and any half-decent, 2d library should support this.

I'm willing to scrap opengl, but I can't find another graphics library as of yet. Something with the functionality of pygame would be more than sufficient.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use shaders it is supereasy. If not I guess you have to find another library.

I do recommend you to use shaders and a way of removing the background is to discard the fragment if the fragment's color is the backgroundcolor (this is in the fragmentshader). There are a lot of tutorials on shaders on the internet and it is the way to go nowadays.

Comment: If it won't drain performance, than I'm fine with this solution. Can you explain that tutorial? I know shaders are separate programs, do I have to import JAR files for the calls to be recognized?

Comment: A shader is written as a string (or loaded from a textfile), then opengl compiles it and sends it to the graphicscard. I don't know box2d and I don't know how much you have done in OpenGL, but if you want to learn to write shaders (which isn't hard) then there are tutorials on the web that teach just that. By the way, shaders are very fast when it comes to performance since they execute in parallel.